# How to Create a SPARQL Query to Retrieve Objects Linked to a Subject in RDF/XML?

Tags: xml, sparql, rdf

I am working with RDF/XML data and need help creating a SPARQL query. My data is structured as follows:

```
<dm:DifferenceModel>
  <dm:forwardDifferences rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <cim:Location rdf:ID="id_1">...</cim:Location>
    <cim:PSRType rdf:ID="id_2">...</cim:PSRType>
    <cim:Junction rdf:ID="id_3">
      <cim:IdentifiedObject.mRID>001</cim:IdentifiedObject.mRID>
      ...
      <cim:PowerSystemResource.PSRType rdf:resource="#id_2"/>
      <cim:PowerSystemResource.Location rdf:resource="#id_1"/>
    </cim:Junction>
  </dm:forwardDifferences>
</dm:DifferenceModel>
```

I need to retrieve all objects that are linked to the **`cim:Junction`**  through the **`rdf:resource`** attribute. Specifically, I am interested in fetching data related to the **`cim:PowerSystemResource.PSRType`** and **`cim:PowerSystemResource.Location`** of the junction.

Could someone guide me on how to formulate a SPARQL query for this purpose? I am relatively new to SPARQL and RDF/XML and would appreciate any examples or explanations of how to approach this.

Comment: the first step I always suggest is to look at your data in Turtle format instead of RDF/XML. Turtle is way closer to SPARQL. Especially, you would see that RDF/XML syntax constructs like `rdf:resource` are not relavnt to build the SPARQL query. In your case, you have the subject given, and you always are interested in two specific predicates. This is almost all of the query, all you have to do is to generate two triple patterns with the given subject and the corresponding predicate.

Comment: Other than that, it's not fully clear from your question what exactly is the subject you are interested in - is it the difference model? Or just all junctions with the properties? So, do you need `SELECT * {?s a cim:Junction . ?s cim:PowerSystemResource.PSRType ?psr_type . ?s cim:PowerSystemResource.Location ?psr_location}` or something else?

Comment: Your xml is not valid.  The namespaces dm and cim are not defined.

Comment: @UninformedUser Initially, I was trying to collect all junctions with the properties because I wasn't able to do that. However, what I need is to identify a junction (with all the properties) that possesses a specific PSRTType. Thank you so much for the clarification; the query was successful, and the turtle format helped me to see things better.